Problems with the Truffle extension in Visual Studio Code
A few days ago I started a course in which they are teaching us programming in the blockchain, in one of the parts of the course, they tell us to install an extension called "Truffle" in Visual Studio Code. Before installing it, I already had Node.js, Git and npm installed on my computer.
It keeps telling me that I'm missing Node.js.
What do you think it is?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I removed Node.js and Visual Studio Code to see if the problem was solved and it didn't fix it.
After that I added the path in the Windows internal variables to see if that was it and it didn't work either, so far those have been the solutions I have done
